# Creating a ranking for lines of text file and keeping only top lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

Let's say I have a text file with thousands of lines of the following form:

```
Word Number1 Number2
```

In this text file, the "Word" is indeed some word that changes from one line to another, and the numbers are likewise changing numbers. However, some of these words are the same... Consider the following example:

```
Hello 5 7
Hey 3 2
Hi 7 3
Hi 5 2
Hello 1 4
Hey 5 2
Hello 8 1
```

What would be a python script that reads the text file and keeps only the lines that contain the highest Number1 for any given Word (deleting all lines that do not satisfy this condition)? The output for the above example with such a script would be:

```
Hi 7 3
Hey 5 2
Hello 8 1
```

Note: the order of the lines in the output is irrelevant, all that matters is that the above condition is satisfied. Also, if for a given Word, the highest Number1 is the same for two or more lines, the output should keep only one of them, such that there is only one occurence of any Word in the output.

I've no clue how to approach the deletion aspect, but I can guess (perhaps incorrectly) that the first step would be to make a list from all the lines in the text file, i.e.

```
List1 = open("textfile.txt").readlines()
```

At any rate, many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: why not use a dict? or if the order is important, an ordered dict? every time you encounter a word, check if its in the dict and act accordingly..

Comment: What if there are two lines with the same word and the same number - do you want to keep both or just one?

Comment: I would want to keep only one (I forgot to mention that though, since given the nature of my particular text file that shouldn't happen) - I'll add that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because file objects are iterable, it is not necessary to do the readlines up front. So let's open the file and then just iterate over it using a for loop.

```
fin = open('sometext.txt')
```

We create a dictionary to hold the results, as we go.

```
topwords = dict()
```

Iterating now, over the lines in the file:

```
for line in fin:
```

We strip off the new line characters and split the lines into individual strings, based on where the spaces are (the default behavior for split()).

```
    word, val1, val2 = line.strip().split()
    val1 = int(val1)
```

We check to see if we have already seen the word, if yes, we then check to see if the first value is greater than the first value previously stored.

```
    if word in topwords:
        if val1 > topwords[word][0]:
            topwords[word] = [val1, val2]
    else:
        topwords[word] = [val1, val2]
```

Once we finish parsing all the words, we go back and iterate over the top words and print the results to the screen.

```
for word in topwords:
    output = '{} {} {}'.format(word, *topwords[word])
    print(output)
```

The **final script** looks like this:

```
fin = open('sometext.txt')
topwords = dict()
for line in fin:
    word, val1, val2 = line.strip().split()
    val1 = int(val1)
    if word in topwords:
        if val1 > topwords[word][0]:
            topwords[word] = [val1, val2]
    else:
        topwords[word] = [val1, val2]
for word in topwords:
    output = '{} {} {}'.format(word, *topwords[word])
    print(output)
```

Comment: `val1` is a string, so you are comparing your values in lexicographic, not numeric, order.  So, you would have `"2" > "12"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('the_file.txt')]

other_f = {i[0]:map(int, i[1:]) for i in f}


for i in f:
   if other_f[i[0]][0] < int(i[1]):
       other_f[i[0]] = map(int, i[1:])

new_f = open('the_file.txt', 'w')
for a, b in other_f.items():
    new_f.write(a + " "+' '.join(map(str, b))+"\n")

new_f.close()
```

Output:

```
Hi 7 3
Hello 8 1
Hey 5 2
```

Comment: the readlines() call is not required here. Python will gladly parse over the file object created by your open() call. Using readlines() unnecessarily creates a list in memory, whereas the open() call creates essentially an iterable object (thus conserving some processing time and some memory).

Comment: @E.Ducateme Thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the lines in a `dict`, with the words as keys. To make things easier, you can store a tuple with the value of the first numeric field (converted to integer, otherwise you would sort by lexicographic order) and the line.

We use `dict.setdefault` in case we encounter the word for the first time.

```
highest = {}

with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, val, _ = line.split(' ', 2)
        val = int(val)
        if val > highest.setdefault(name, (val, line))[0]:
            highest[name] = (val, line)

out = [tup[1] for name, tup in highest.items()]

print(''.join(out))

# Hey 5 2
# Hello 8 1
# Hi 7 3
```

Answer (score 1):

first [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) the list with 1st and 2nd column as the key from high to low

then remove the duplicate items

```
list1 = open(r'textfile.txt').read().splitlines()
output = sorted(list1, key=lambda x:(x.split()[0], int(x.split()[1])), reverse=True)

uniq_key = []
for i in sorted_dat:
  key = i.split()[0]
  if key in uniq_key:
    output.remove(i)
  else:
    uniq_key.append(key)

>>> output
['Hi 7 3', 'Hey 5 2', 'Hello 8 1']
```